# Can't run Homey app run oin MacOS (M processor)

Tags: homey

I try to simply run the deafult app created on my Mac, using command "Homey app run"  but get this error.

*connect ENOENT /var/run/docker.sock

Could not connect to Docker. Is it running?
If you haven't installed Docker yet, please download & install it first:*

Docker is installed but don't know if I need to download or start anything else.

Default app create from command "Homey app create".

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, what solved it was the changes I did in the Docker Desktop Settings.

In Advanced:

- Set "System" and not "User" as CLI tools.
- Enable default Docker socket

In Features in development:

- Set Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation

Not sure what changes did the trick :-)